# How to perform "optional unwrapping" to a function using generic parameters

Tags: swift, generics

I'll begin with small code examples, made as simple as possible to sum up the problem.

Let's say I've got a function defined as follow :

```
func doSomething<T>(using f: (String, (T) -> Void) -> Void, key: String) {
   f("test", {
      object in
      // do something with object using key
      //...
   })

}
```

I've got a bunch of auto generated classes with class methods, for exemple :

```
class MyClass {
   var prop1: String = ""
}

class MyClassAPI {

   class func f1(param: String, completion: (MyClass) -> Void) {
      let mc = MyClass()
      mc.prop1 = "hello"
      completion(mc)
   }
}
```

Then, I got a whole set of key/functions couples in a dictionary :

```
// Any because of cast problem !
let keyFunctions: [String: Any] = [ 
    "first" : MyClassAPI.f1,
    "second" : MySecondClassAPI.f2,
    "third" : MyThirdClassAPI.f3
    //...
]
```

Finally, i'll iterate through all the keys/function to call `doSomething`:

```
for (k, f) in keyFunctions {
   // This line doesn't work as the compiler complain about typing errors
   doSomething(using: f, key: k)
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I can't cast my functions to the right type to pass them to `doSomething` :

Xcode suppose to force cast using  `f as! (String, (_) -> ()) -> Void` then gives me an error, _ is not a type.

I tried to be more permissive using `if let uf = f as? (String, (Any) -> Void) -> Void`with no chance.

I read the whole generics pages of Swift manual without any hint on how to achieve this.

Please let me know of any existing way to perform such things using genericity.

Comment: These are called higher kinded types. Swift doesn't support them.

Comment: Do functions `f1`, `f2` and `f3` in your dictionary return different classes? Could they at least conform to the same protocol?

Comment: @Dimitry No, they don't return from different classes, in fact one of their parameters is a closure, each of one taking a different type as a parameter.
I think I'll have to make them conform to a protocol, thanks

Comment: @Hamish Because I won't be able to pass them to my function parameter as XCode complain about their type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Any` make a more specific type for a block

```
let keyFunctions: [String: (String) -> Any]
```

Then, at least, your will compile and `doSomething` will be called.
However, there is no point in making it generic, as `T` will always be `Any` . If `doSomething` relies on common behaviour between your classes, then it would make sense to define a protocol for all of them.

If you actually want to have information about your classes, then you can introduce a non generic class that would keep this info:

```
class Wrap {
    var resultType: Any.Type
    let f: (String) -> Any

    init<T>(_ f: @escaping (String) -> T) {
        self.f = f
        resultType = T.self
    }
}

let keyFunctions: [String: Wrap] = [
    "first" : Wrap(MyClassAPI.f1),
    "second" : Wrap(MySecondClassAPI.f2)
]
```

But `resultType` can not be used in casting later though.

Comment: I'll give it a shot but I don't think I'll be able to call the functions with proper parameters in my doSomething function.
I changed my code to be closer to my real problem, please let me know if it change something or not

Comment: I managed to make it work as I didn't in fact need to know the class of the objects in the completion block (see edited question), +1 for the wrapper idea

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it this way :

```
func doSomething<T>(using f: (String, (Any) -> Void, key: String, type: T.Type) -> Void, key: String) {
   f("test", {
      object in
      guard let o as? type else { return }
      // do something with o using key
      //...
   })
}

let keyFunctions: [String: (String, (Any) -> Void)] = [ 
   "first" : MyClassAPI.f1,
   "second" : MySecondClassAPI.f2,
   "third" : MyThirdClassAPI.f3
   //...
```

]